# In R, how do I recursively store columns of a data frame as a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I want to recursively go through the columns of a data frame and select each column to make a boxplot against a given column.
Here is my attempt

```
#define dataframe
library(ggplot2)
df <- mpg

#get unique column names
IDs <- unique( colnames(df) )
for (name in IDs){ 
  #goal: store column as a data frame, actual: store column as a list 
  temp <- df[name]
  #plot column of data vs cty miles per gallon
  boxplot(temp ~ df$cty)
}
```

I get this error (because it needs to be a dataframe not a list):

> Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = temp ~ df$cty) :
> invalid type (list) for variable 'temp'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you initialized `df` let's try to extract the `cyl` column the way you did:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- mpg
str(df["cyl"])
```

From the result you can see that this extracted a tibble with only one row. It did not extract the one row as a vector. boxplot expects `temp` to be a vector. That explains the error message. A tibble is a data.frame and a data.frame ist not a vector.

Extracting a vector could be done like this:

```
> str(df[,"cyl", drop = TRUE])
 int [1:234] 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 4 4 4 ...
```

or like this:

```
> str(df[["cyl"]])
 int [1:234] 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 4 4 4 ...
```

So changing your code in two places we could write

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- mpg[,c(3,4,5,8,9)] # only numeric columns

IDs <- unique( colnames(df) )
for (name in IDs){ 
  temp <- df[, name, drop = TRUE] # using the drop argument
  boxplot(temp ~ df$cty)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If we are doing this on numeric columns, get the `names` of the numeric column by checking if the columns are `numeric`.  Then use the OP's code.  Here, we create the formula with `reformulate` by specifying the `response` and independent columns and get the `boxplot` stored in a `list`

```
IDs <- setdiff(names(which(sapply(df, is.numeric))), 'cty')
lst <- vector('list', length(IDs))
names(lst) <- IDs
for(name in IDs) {
    lst[[name]] <- boxplot(reformulate('cty', response = name), df)
}
```